# Why matlab does not finish calculation?

Tags: matlab

I got stuck in simple problem I think. I'm testing a matrix with parameters, so when I replaced parameters with their values it gave me this result :

```
>> syms l t r
>> syms M(l, t, r)
>> M(l, t, r) = [.... ... ...; etc]
>> Mat(pi/3,pi/3,pi/3)

ans =

[          -1/8, -(3*3^(1/2))/8,        3/4]
[ (3*3^(1/2))/8,           -5/8, -3^(1/2)/4]
[           3/4,      3^(1/2)/4,        1/2]
```

Why the calculation isn't completed even though the matrix uses simple trigonometrical functions?

Comment: Because, somewhere along the way, you declared something to be symbolic (probably using `syms`).  I'm guessing `Mat`.

Comment: you can use `double(ans)` to convert your answer to approximate format

Comment: yes I did. is it the problem here ?

Comment: Thanks brainkz, the problem is solved using double(ans). It would be great if you give brief explanation why did that happen in the first place and if there is other solution.